# jquery. livequery() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, livequery

trying to run jquery plugin "livequery" to highlight some words in a dynamically generated search results doesn't work ! 
However adding an alert() function before excuting the code make the highlighting appear! so what is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
     $('#searchResults').livequery(function(el){
     // alert('test');
     $( '#searchResults' ).highlight( highlightArray );
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding some delay by `setTimeout()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
     $('#searchResults').livequery(function(el){
         // alert('test');
         setTimeout(function(){
             $( '#searchResults' ).highlight( highlightArray );
         },400);
     });
});
```

Comment: nice idea! however it has some disadvantages like if the page content takes a longer time than specified,  it will not run...it is really nice idea but I hope I can find any better one.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you still use livequery? It is not necessary by now. It was before jQuery delegated events. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675526/is-livequery-deprecated) for more informations. Use .on() instead of livequery().

So you can just do

```
$(document).on('change','#searchResults',function(el){
    $('#searchResults').highlight(highlightArray);
});
```

Comment: I tried something like       $(document).on('change','#searchResults',function(){
      alert("test");   
     });

Comment: still not working, the alert does not show up, idon't know why (Im 100% sure that #searchResults Id is the targeted div)

Comment: Have a closer look at how .on() works. You don't have to look for the target div but for the element that triggers the event. Event can be any and triggering element too. Inside you will run the animation on any element in the Dom

Comment: I tried "body"  instead of "#searchResults" still no alert aplears although new data (seatch results) always appear on the page

Comment: Body is not the element to refer to. Please set up a fiddle if you want further debug and have a look at the documentation for .on