# Jquery livequery 'click' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, livequery

I've got a problem with my Jquery, the alert doesn't pop.

Here is the code :

HTML (I've this div 4 times, which is a button) :

```
<div class="grid4 text_center" style = "margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;">
<input value="Calculer" class="bouton btvalid btlong250 validation" type="submit">
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.grid4 text_center .bouton btvalid btlong250 validation').livequery('click', function () {    
var sTest = 'Click';
alert('' + sTest);  
});
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `livequery` plugin???

Comment: I read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675526/is-livequery-deprecated that "livequery is dead." Why did it die?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to this:

```
$('.grid4.text_center .bouton.btvalid.btlong250.validation')
```

space separated css class names should be concat with a `.`, so for div that you can do `.grid4.text_center` then a space  now same with the input's css classes `.bouton.btvalid.btlong250.validation`.

---

May be this way you should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grid4.text_center .bouton.btvalid.btlong250.validation').livequery(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var sTest = 'Click';
      alert('' + sTest);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid4 text_center" style="margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;">
  <input value="Calculer" class="bouton btvalid btlong250 validation" type="submit">
</div>

<script>
  (function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
      factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
      factory(jQuery);
    }
  }(function($, undefined) {

    function _match(me, query, fn, fn2) {
      return me.selector == query.selector &&
        me.context == query.context &&
        (!fn || fn.$lqguid == query.fn.$lqguid) &&
        (!fn2 || fn2.$lqguid == query.fn2.$lqguid);
    }

    $.extend($.fn, {
      livequery: function(fn, fn2) {
        var me = this,
          q;

        // See if Live Query already exists
        $.each($jQlq.queries, function(i, query) {
          if (_match(me, query, fn, fn2))
          // Found the query, exit the each loop
            return (q = query) && false;
        });

        // Create new Live Query if it wasn't found
        q = q || new $jQlq(me.selector, me.context, fn, fn2);

        // Make sure it is running
        q.stopped = false;

        // Run it immediately for the first time
        q.run();

        // Contnue the chain
        return me;
      },

      expire: function(fn, fn2) {
        var me = this;

        // Find the Live Query based on arguments and stop it
        $.each($jQlq.queries, function(i, query) {
          if (_match(me, query, fn, fn2) && !me.stopped)
            $jQlq.stop(query.id);
        });

        // Continue the chain
        return me;
      }
    });

    var $jQlq = $.livequery = function(selector, context, fn, fn2) {
      var me = this;

      me.selector = selector;
      me.context = context;
      me.fn = fn;
      me.fn2 = fn2;
      me.elements = $([]);
      me.stopped = false;

      // The id is the index of the Live Query in $.livequery.queries
      me.id = $jQlq.queries.push(me) - 1;

      // Mark the functions for matching later on
      fn.$lqguid = fn.$lqguid || $jQlq.guid++;
      if (fn2) fn2.$lqguid = fn2.$lqguid || $jQlq.guid++;

      // Return the Live Query
      return me;
    };

    $jQlq.prototype = {
      stop: function() {
        var me = this;
        // Short-circuit if stopped
        if (me.stopped) return;

        if (me.fn2)
        // Call the second function for all matched elements
          me.elements.each(me.fn2);

        // Clear out matched elements
        me.elements = $([]);

        // Stop the Live Query from running until restarted
        me.stopped = true;
      },

      run: function() {
        var me = this;
        // Short-circuit if stopped
        if (me.stopped) return;

        var oEls = me.elements,
          els = $(me.selector, me.context),
          newEls = els.not(oEls),
          delEls = oEls.not(els);

        // Set elements to the latest set of matched elements
        me.elements = els;

        // Call the first function for newly matched elements
        newEls.each(me.fn);

        // Call the second function for elements no longer matched
        if (me.fn2)
          delEls.each(me.fn2);
      }
    };

    $.extend($jQlq, {
      guid: 0,
      queries: [],
      queue: [],
      running: false,
      timeout: null,
      registered: [],

      checkQueue: function() {
        if ($jQlq.running && $jQlq.queue.length) {
          var length = $jQlq.queue.length;
          // Run each Live Query currently in the queue
          while (length--)
            $jQlq.queries[$jQlq.queue.shift()].run();
        }
      },

      pause: function() {
        // Don't run anymore Live Queries until restarted
        $jQlq.running = false;
      },

      play: function() {
        // Restart Live Queries
        $jQlq.running = true;
        // Request a run of the Live Queries
        $jQlq.run();
      },

      registerPlugin: function() {
        $.each(arguments, function(i, n) {
          // Short-circuit if the method doesn't exist
          if (!$.fn[n] || $.inArray(n, $jQlq.registered) > 0) return;

          // Save a reference to the original method
          var old = $.fn[n];

          // Create a new method
          $.fn[n] = function() {
            // Call the original method
            var r = old.apply(this, arguments);

            // Request a run of the Live Queries
            $jQlq.run();

            // Return the original methods result
            return r;
          };

          $jQlq.registered.push(n);
        });
      },

      run: function(id) {
        if (id !== undefined) {
          // Put the particular Live Query in the queue if it doesn't already exist
          if ($.inArray(id, $jQlq.queue) < 0)
            $jQlq.queue.push(id);
        } else
        // Put each Live Query in the queue if it doesn't already exist
          $.each($jQlq.queries, function(id) {
          if ($.inArray(id, $jQlq.queue) < 0)
            $jQlq.queue.push(id);
        });

        // Clear timeout if it already exists
        if ($jQlq.timeout) clearTimeout($jQlq.timeout);
        // Create a timeout to check the queue and actually run the Live Queries
        $jQlq.timeout = setTimeout($jQlq.checkQueue, 20);
      },

      stop: function(id) {
        if (id !== undefined)
        // Stop are particular Live Query
          $jQlq.queries[id].stop();
        else
        // Stop all Live Queries
          $.each($jQlq.queries, $jQlq.prototype.stop);
      }
    });

    // Register core DOM manipulation methods
    $jQlq.registerPlugin('append', 'prepend', 'after', 'before', 'wrap', 'attr', 'removeAttr', 'addClass', 'removeClass', 'toggleClass', 'empty', 'remove', 'html', 'prop', 'removeProp');

    // Run Live Queries when the Document is ready
    $(function() {
      $jQlq.play();
    });

  }));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still don't have my alert pop up.

Comment: Ok it seems that my mistake was made earlier, i tried to put the variable and the alert into the document ready without using the livequery and it still doesn't work, does it mean that my script src is not working?

Comment: @JulienS added a snippet for you, if you are reffering to the library from github then it could output some error see web console or download it locally and then you can add livequery after jQuery.

Comment: It's working now, I'll have to make some searches to understand how everything is working I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to this.

```
$('.grid4 .validation');
```