# Jquery. Hide other elements, except this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I‘m using Pollate Template for creating polls. There is a list of user's created Polls, after clicking 3 dots (menu icon), the dropdown list shows up with the option to delete this poll. If the submenu is shown and you click anywhere on the screen it hiding.

But I found a bug, that if you clicking on another sub-menu icon it not hiding other sub-menus (look at the image below).

It should be hidden when clicking anywhere, even if it's a sub-menu icon of another entry.

[image: bug]

There is HTML structure:

```
    <div class="pl-options">
         <a href="#" class="pl-user-options"></a>
         <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
     </div>
    <div class="pl-options">
         <a href="#" class="pl-user-options"></a>
         <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
     </div>
```

After clicking `a` - dropdown shows up.

There is JQuery:

```
$.puerto_droped = function( prtclick, prtlist = "ul.dropdown" ){
    $(prtclick).livequery('click', function(){
        var ul = $(this).parent();
        if( ul.find(prtlist).hasClass('open') ){
            ul.find(prtlist).removeClass('open');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if(prtclick == ".pl-mobile-menu") $('body').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            ul.find(prtlist).addClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if(prtclick == ".pl-mobile-menu") $('body').addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("html, body").livequery('click', function(){
        $(prtclick).parent().find(prtlist).removeClass('open');
        $(prtclick).removeClass('active');
        if(prtclick == ".pl-mobile-menu") $('body').removeClass('active');
    });
}
```

`prtclick` -> `.pl-user-options`

I think that this function `$("html, body").livequery('click', function(){...` should be edited, but can't achieve it successfully. I've tried in many ways but failed.

One of my tries was:

```
$(prtclick).click(function(evt){   
    $(prtclick).find(prtlist).removeClass('open');
    $(prtclick).removeClass('active');
    if(prtclick == ".pl-mobile-menu") $('body').removeClass('active');
});
```

But now it not showing sub-menu at all. I need to make an exception for the current entry. Have you any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: can you create demo code for above ?

Comment: But livequery died 7 years ago... You should use regular event delegation. See [is Livequery deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675526/is-livequery-deprecated)

Comment: You can exclude a element of the *jQuery* collection with `$.not()`. Ex.: `$('ul.dropdown.open').not($(this).parent())...`

Comment: the structure youve shared is for one poll or the `.row` is parent of polls?

Answer (score 0):

Before you check for `.open` class, you can toggle off all other `ul.dropdown`s.

```
$(this).closest('.row').siblings('.row').removeClass('active')
    .find('ul.dropdown').removeClass('open');
```

Get current clicked `a` main parent which has 'row' class,
get its siblings, remove 'active' class of them,
get all `ul.dropdown`s inside those siblings and remove 'open' class of those `ul`s